# PDF corrupted on Outlook with AVG anti-virus software installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdf-generation

we are having the problem of sending PDF attachment using ActionMailer.

The PDF file was combined from 2 PDF files using `combine_pdf` gem.

- A normal PDF file with our logo.
- A `docx` converted PDF using http://convertapi.com

The combined PDF file is stored on AWS S3. What we did is just attach it using `open-uri`

```
require 'open-uri'

class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def employer_notification application_id
    @application = JobApplication.find_by_id application_id
    return unless @application
    attachments[@application.cv_name] = {
      mime_type: 'application/pdf',
      content: open(@application.cv_url(900)).read
    }
    mail(
      from: "#{@application.fullname}<test@myapp.com>",
      to: @application.job.employer_emails(", "),
      reply_to: @application.email,
      subject: "Application for #{@application.job.title}"
      )
  end
end
```

We used Mandrill to send out the emails over the internet and something strangely happened. Some PDF could be viewed properly, some contained font errors and the converted PDF part went blank.

But if we turned off AVG anti-virus, it worked perfectly.

Does anyone have the same problem before? May I know how a PDF file is considered malicious?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to send the email with a pdf file attached manually? Do you get the same results? If so, I'd suggest contacting AVG. There can be a bug...

Comment: I've tried and was able to open it, it even could able to display nicely on my handphone. I also did some researches and learned that a PDF is considered malicious if it contains some sort of Javascript codes, however didn't find any in my converted PDF. Does it help to find the problem easier if I submit the PDF files? Thank you.